# Realtek ethernet driver issue, network unclaimed, ubuntu 18.04

Tags: networking, drivers, ethernet

i'm getting error network UNCLAIMED, and i see through the forums that it states the drivers. well, my kernel is 5.3.0-20-generic, and it states when i try to install the drivers, its the latest...and its not working. do i need to downgrade to the prior version of the drivers or wait till the create it for this kernel? funny thing is my wireless interface is working...any help in the right directions, thanks.

```
$ sudo lshw -C network 
  *-network UNCLAIMED       
       description: Ethernet controller
       product: RTL8111/8168/8411 PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet Controller
       vendor: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd.
       physical id: 0.1
       bus info: pci@0000:01:00.1
       version: 12
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm msi pciexpress msix vpd bus_master cap_list
       configuration: latency=0
       resources: ioport:e000(size=256) memory:df214000-df214fff memory:df210000-df213fff
```

```
$ sudo apt-get install r8168-dkms
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
r8168-dkms is already the newest version (8.046.00-1).
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 16 not upgraded.
```

Comment: i was able to fix issue, by installing updated or latest realtek drivers:)

Comment: Would you be willing [to post an answer](https://askubuntu.com/help/self-answer) explaining how you did that? I believe that may help others who find this by searching.

Comment: How do you install it if you do not have internet access?

Comment: @Eliah Kagan sorry for the late post, resolution below.

Comment: @ComputerScientist be resourceful :)

Answer (score 2):

You don't need `r8168-dkms` with new kernels.

Remove it by `sudo apt purge r8168-dkms` and the adapter will be managed by the kernel in-tree module.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem with my System76 Gazelle.  I don't know why, but running:

```
sudo modprobe r8168
```

caused it to work.

It gave me this error when I ran the command:

```
modprobe: FATAL: Module r8168 not found in directory /lib/modules/5.3.0-7625-generic
```

but it turned on.

Answer (score 0):

I haven't got high enough rep to comment, but I had this exact problem. I solved it by downloading the latest Realtek 8168 driver and installing. I don't think Realtek provide the drivers any more, but they have kindly been archived here: https://github.com/mtorromeo/r8168/releases

1. `sudo apt-get install build-essential linux-headers-$(uname -r)`
2. `sudo sh -c 'echo blacklist r8169 >> /etc/modprobe.d/blacklist.conf'`
3. Download latest tar.gz from https://github.com/mtorromeo/r8168/releases
4. `tar xfvz r8168-X.XXX.XX.tar.gz` (replace XXs with name of file you downloaded)
5. `cd r8168-8.XXX.XX`
6. `sudo ./autorun.sh`

Hope that helps

Comment: Hi @qualia, after you do this how do you actually get the error (UNCLAIMED) to go away? Is there anything else? I followed your instructions and rebooting did not seem to fix.

Answer (score -1):

resolution at the time of incident on a system76 lemur6, which was back 11-7-19, so you would need to make sure to get the latest driver:

grab a copy of the latest r8168 driver (or download it via another computer and put it on USB storage)

wget http://mirrors.edge.kernel.org/ubuntu/pool/universe/r/r8168/r8168-dkms_8.047.02-1_all.deb
Install that driver (will automatically regenerate initramfs kernel image with integrated driver)

dpkg -i r8168-dkms_8.047.02-1_all.deb or use gdebi package installer (log below)

(Reading database ... 301468 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to unpack .../r8168-dkms_8.047.02-1_all.deb ...

### -------- Uninstall Beginning --------
Module:  r8168
Version: 8.046.00
Kernel:  5.0.0-21-generic (x86_64)

Status: Before uninstall, this module version was ACTIVE on this kernel.

r8168.ko:

- Uninstallation

  - Deleting from: /lib/modules/5.0.0-21-generic/updates/dkms/
- Original module

  - No original module was found for this module on this kernel.
  - Use the dkms install command to reinstall any previous module version.

depmod...

Backing up initrd.img-5.0.0-21-generic to /boot/initrd.img-5.0.0-21-generic.old-dkms
Making new initrd.img-5.0.0-21-generic
(If next boot fails, revert to initrd.img-5.0.0-21-generic.old-dkms image)
update-initramfs...............

DKMS: uninstall completed.

### -------- Uninstall Beginning --------
Module:  r8168
Version: 8.046.00
Kernel:  5.0.0-32-generic (x86_64)

Status: Before uninstall, this module version was ACTIVE on this kernel.

r8168.ko:

- Uninstallation

  - Deleting from: /lib/modules/5.0.0-32-generic/updates/dkms/
- Original module

  - No original module was found for this module on this kernel.
  - Use the dkms install command to reinstall any previous module version.

depmod...

Backing up initrd.img-5.0.0-32-generic to /boot/initrd.img-5.0.0-32-generic.old-dkms
Making new initrd.img-5.0.0-32-generic
(If next boot fails, revert to initrd.img-5.0.0-32-generic.old-dkms image)
update-initramfs.............................

DKMS: uninstall completed.

---

### Deleting module version: 8.046.00
completely from the DKMS tree.

Done.
Unpacking r8168-dkms (8.047.02-1) over (8.046.00-1) ...
Setting up r8168-dkms (8.047.02-1) ...
Loading new r8168-8.047.02 DKMS files...
Building for 5.3.0-20-generic
Building initial module for 5.3.0-20-generic
Secure Boot not enabled on this system.
Done.

r8168:
Running module version sanity check.

- Original module

  - No original module exists within this kernel
- Installation

  - Installing to /lib/modules/5.3.0-20-generic/updates/dkms/

depmod...

Backing up initrd.img-5.3.0-20-generic to /boot/initrd.img-5.3.0-20-generic.old-dkms
Making new initrd.img-5.3.0-20-generic
(If next boot fails, revert to initrd.img-5.3.0-20-generic.old-dkms image)
update-initramfs..............................

DKMS: install completed.
update-initramfs: deferring update (trigger activated)
Processing triggers for initramfs-tools (0.130ubuntu3.9) ...
update-initramfs: Generating /boot/initrd.img-5.3.0-20-generic
W: initramfs-tools configuration sets RESUME=UUID=1ea780e4-c2fa-4021-991a-a0cd0a5fff31
W: but no matching swap device is available.

- Remove elder driver, blacklist it, and use newer one

$rmmod r8169

$echo "blacklist r8169" > /etc/modprobe.d/blacklist.conf

$modprobe r8168`

(and try if everything works after a fresh boot)