# Networking Gone After Update

Tags: networking, grub2, kernel, updates

Running Xubuntu 20.04.01. Got the popup this morning that updates needed to be installed so I clicked okay and rebooted when finished. After reboot the network is gone and the server is a large brick since it can't get on the network. Tried holding shift during boot to see a grub menu to maybe boot into the previous kernel but no grub menu ever appears, it always just boots into this broken 5.8.0 kernel. Not sure what to do. Who knew an average, ordinary software update could brick my machine?

lshw: https://i.stack.imgur.com/f2TMz.jpg

lspci/ip/ifconfig: https://i.stack.imgur.com/BHCYe.jpg

Any ideas how to get my network back?

Comment: Please don't post screenshots of text.

Comment: On newest kernel, that solution works https://askubuntu.com/a/1211166

Comment: @mayer Kind of hard to do that with no network connection

Comment: @Pilot6 Why even bother commenting when you have absolutely nothing meaningful to contribute?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Kernel Ubuntu, with Linux 5.8.0-x is not compatible with RealTek ethernet adapters**

*Workaround*

https://www.linuxquestions.org/questions/linux-server-73/updated-system-all-networking-lost-following-reboot-4175690186/